Retrieve a single relation using TypeORM
From the database, I'd like to retrieve a specific framework and its latest chapter if there is one available.
The SQL query should look like this:
SELECT
    "framework".*,
    "chapter".*
FROM
    "framework"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "chapter" ON "chapter"."frameworkId" = "framework"."id"
WHERE
    "framework"."id" = 'some id'
ORDER BY
    "chapter"."order" DESC
LIMIT
    1

What would the TypeORM code look like? My current TypeORM solution creates two queries and will retrieve all chapters instead of just one. Bonus: Can someone explain why two queries are used?
await this.frameworkRepository.find({
  where: {
    id: 'some id',
  },
  relations: {
    chapters: {},
  },
  order: {
    chapters: {
      order: 'DESC',
    },
  },
  take: 1,
});

Models:
@Entity()
@Index(['name', 'organisation'], { unique: true })
export class Framework {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Chapter, (c) => c.framework, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  chapters: Chapter[];
}

@Entity()
export class Chapter {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  // ToDo: add string to number converter
  @Column()
  order: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Framework, (f) => f.chapters, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'frameworkId' })
  framework: Framework;

  @Column()
  frameworkId: string;
}


Check this link question already raised & discussed
